# Why I can't check spurious wakeup by if condition instead of while loop

Tags: java, spurious-wakeup

I'm currently reading *Java The Complete Reference* book, multithread section.
There is an example about handling **spurious wakeup**.
It's the classic producer-consumer example that I bring `get()` method here:

```
synchronized int get() {
    while(!valueSet)
        try {
            wait();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
        }
    System.out.println("Got: " + n);
    valueSet = false;
    notify();
    return n;
}
```

Consider that I change the keyword `while` to `if`.

Even with **spurious wakeup** of the related thread the **if condition** will be checked. So I wonder why we should call to `wait()` within a **loop**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `while` to an `if` would only check the condition before entering `wait`. Spurious wake-up refers to a situation where `wait` is entered *and then returns without satisfying the condition*. In this case `valueSet` could still be `false` when `wait` returns, so the check needs to be repeated.